# Perl: Detect Newline in HTML

Tags: regex, perl

I don't have access to any modules like MoJo but need to capture all of the content between two H3 tags.  Unfortunately, on some pages the H3 tags have newlines/carriage returns (not sure how I can tell which one) while others don't.  I need some regexp to capture either.  Here is the source code for both the scenarios I need to capture:

**1st Scenario**

```
<h3>Summary</h3>
<h3>Solution</h3>
```

**2nd Scenario**

```
<h3>Summary
</h3>
<h3>Solution
</h3>
```

My current code looks something like this:

```
if ($doc =~ m{<h3>Summary(?s:.)</h3>(.+?)<h3>Solution(?s:.)</h3>}si)
{
    my $summaryp = $1;
    $summaryp =~ s{<.+?>}{}gsi;
...
}
```

I've tried a number of variations on \n, \r, (.+?), \S\s, etc. without success in capturing scenario #2.

For thoroughness sake, I'm not sure if there's a space or two before the newline so I'll need something that accounts for any character, space or line changes.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting from the above?

Comment: @stevieb - This is just a selector (coming for a jQuery mindset) but to answer your question, there is a bunch of HTML in between the two H3's that should be returned.  Once i have it, I start my string manipulation routines, e.g., remove HTML tags, convert underscores, etc.

Comment: does the following work? `m{<h3>Summary.*?</h3>(.*?)<h3>Solution.*?</h3>}si`

Comment: Crap - Yes!  I knew it was something simple.  Go ahead and answer the question so I can give you credit.  BTW, I tried (.*?) - what's the difference between that and .*?

Comment: `(.*?)` captures and would be included in one of the numbered vars, so it would populate `$1` if placed before your real capture. You can avoid capturing by putting `?:` inside of the parens: `(?:.*?)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments on the question, `m{<h3>Summary.*?</h3>(.*?)<h3>Solution.*?</h3>}si` should do what is needed.

Here's the full example I tested with:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $doc1 = <<EOF;
<h3>Summary
</h3>
blah 1
this is some stuff
<h3>Solution
</h3>
EOF

my $doc2 = <<EOF2;
<h3>Summary</h3>
blah 2
this is more stuff
<h3>Solution</h3>
EOF2

for my $doc ($doc1, $doc2){
    if ($doc =~ m{<h3>Summary.*?</h3>(.*?)<h3>Solution.*?</h3>}si){
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
blah 1
this is some stuff


blah 2
this is more stuff
```